# Rosdep experienced an internal error

Tags: ros, rosdep-install

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey all, I seem to be having this problem whenever using rosdep

> ERROR: Rosdep experienced an internal
> error: [Errno 13] Permission denied:
> '/home/barrybear/.ros/rosdep/sources.cache/index'
> Please go to the rosdep page [1] and
> file a bug report with the stack trace
> below. [1] :
> http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosdep
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File
> "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rosdep2/main.py",
> line 116, in rosdep_main
> exit_code = _rosdep_main(args)   File
> "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rosdep2/main.py",
> line 257, in _rosdep_main
> return _package_args_handler(command, parser, options, args)   File
> "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rosdep2/main.py",
> line 331, in _package_args_handler
> lookup = _get_default_RosdepLookup(options)   File
> "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rosdep2/main.py",
> line 107, in _get_default_RosdepLookup
> verbose=options.verbose)   File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rosdep2/sources_list.py",
> line 501, in create_default
> sources = load_cached_sources_list(sources_cache_dir=sources_cache_dir,
> verbose=verbose)   File
> "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rosdep2/sources_list.py",
> line 419, in load_cached_sources_list
> with open(cache_index, 'r') as f: IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:
> '/home/barrybear/.ros/rosdep/sources.cache/index'

Whenever I try to apply sudo rosdep, I'll obtain this error:

> ERROR: Rosdep cannot find all required
> resources to answer your query
> Missing resource scan_tools

Can anyone please help me with a fix? Thanks :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/50920/rosdep-experienced-an-internal-error.../) by [barrybear](https://answers.ros.org/users/3741/barrybear/) on ROS Answers with karma: 57 on 2012-12-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First you can verify that all urls listed under /etc/ros/rosdep/sources.list.d/ are valid. For me the file 20-default.list looks like:

```
# os-specific listings first
yaml https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/rosdep/osx-homebrew.yaml osx
yaml https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/rosdep/gentoo.yaml gentoo
# generic
yaml https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/rosdep/base.yaml
yaml https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/rosdep/python.yaml
yaml https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/rosdep/ruby.yaml
gbpdistro https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/releases/fuerte.yaml fuerte
gbpdistro https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/releases/groovy.yaml groovy
```

Second you might have ran "rosdep update" once with sudo and now the file in your home directory are owner my root and not writable by you anymore. You should remove the folder ~/.ros/rosdep and call "rosdep update" again.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2012-12-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [barrybear](https://answers.ros.org/users/3741/barrybear/) on 2012-12-21**:
Thats superb! I've got the same listings as the first, and i rm -rf the rosdep dir and call the update again as stated, now it works! ;) Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I know there's already an answer that worked, but for me, the permission denied error were resolved by running "sudo rosdep fix-permissions" from my /home directory. Not sure if being in the /home directory matters, though.

---

Originally posted by [ElizabethA](https://answers.ros.org/users/26773/elizabetha/) with karma: 120 on 2016-05-20

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Femer](https://answers.ros.org/users/26134/femer/) on 2017-01-19**:
Thanks! This was very useful!